# How should I Arrange my data?

Tags: python

I'd like to log the CPU percentage of each process in different times. I need a data struct that will allow me to save the data like this:

- Explorer.EXE

  - 19:03 | 47%
  - 19:05 | 14%
  - 19:08 | 24%
- Firefox.EXE

  - 19:03 | 21%
  - 19:05 | 14%
  - 19:08 | 2%
- Messenger.EXE

  - 19:03 | 11%
  - 19:05 | 12%
  - 19:08 | 11%

What's the right way to do it? I thought about tuples inside lists inside a list, but the identifier for a list is not a string but a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
data = {
    'Explorer.EXE': [ ("19:03", 47), ("19:05" , 14), ("19:08" , 24)],
    'Firefox.EXE' : [ ("19:03", 21), ("19:05" , 14), ("19:08" , 2) ],
    'Messenger.EXE': [ ("19:03" , 11), ("19:05" , 12), ("19:08" , 11)]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about a dictionary that uses the process name as key: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict

The dictionary value could be a list of tuples.

Comment: ops, I answered too late, it took me a bit to write down the code... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
struct = {
    "Explorer.EXE": [
        (datetime.time(19, 03), .47),
        (datetime.time(19, 05), .14),
        ...
    ],
    "Firefox.EXE": [
        (datetime.time(19, 03), .21),
        (datetime.time(19, 05), .14),
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```